# Extra long query is timing out too often. Help?

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2003

Here's how this particular reporting process is supposed to work:

1. A VBA script tells an Excel file to update it's external data.
2. The Excel file pulls it's data from an adhoc Access 2003 db (stored on the network), does some formatting to pretty it up, and saves the file to a network drive.
3. The VBA script emails it to the data-hungry recipients.

I've been doing this for years for now with the sporadic problem that the machine sometimes hiccups on the data pull.  These are 2 of the error messages I can get:

- The remote server machine does not exist or is unavailable
- Automation error
  The object invoked has disconnected from its clients.

As time has gone on, the queries in the adhoc Access db have grown more and more complex.  Today, 8 more OR criteria clauses were added to one particular query which already had about 10 of them to begin with. The result is when I tried to run the updated report today, it threw errors **4** times before a successful run.

If I had the option, I would edit the queries directly and see if I could improve performance that way, but that is unlikely for political/security reasons.  Hence, I am asking you, oh fine fellow contributors to StackOverflow, for suggestions to make this more reliable.

Comment: Can you copy the access2003 db to the local machine?

Comment: @poweruser I'm so sorry.  Wrap it in a shell script to continually retry until successful, and use the delayed emails for political sway to replace it.  What Os is running the job? maybe StackOverflow can help with the script.

Comment: @rene good call.  add that into the retry script as well PowerUser ;)

Comment: @rene Sorry.  Not trying to poach.  I didn't see your comment until after I submitted my answer.

Comment: Why do you think additional criteria are causing an issue? Are these a chain of ORs that could be converted to IN ("a", "b", "c") instead? Or perhaps you could write them to an INDEXED data table and then join on them? Frankly, I don't think the criteria are the problem. I also don't think it's a system that needs to be replaced, either. The Access database ought to be the most robust link in the chain -- I'd suspect Excel as the problem here, actually, and try moving the scripting in the Access database, and automate Excel from it.

Comment: @David, there are plenty of ways to optimize the queries for speed, but I was trying to avoid that due to the political confrontation.

Comment: @David, regarding the second half of your comment, I'd like to clarify that the VB scripts are run from a 2nd Access db (not Excel). So, the "Controller" Access file tells the Excel file to retrieve the data from the "Database" Access file. I almost never put any code in Excel because the user gets the Macro Warning message.

Answer (score 1):

Your options are pretty limited if you can't improve the queries themselves.  The error messages you are getting (and the fact that they are sporadic) seem to indicate the problems may be caused by the fact that you are running them across the network.

If possible, I would try copying the Access data file down to the machine running the script as the first part of the script.

If you are unable to re-link the tables within Access, you can "fool" Access by using the [`subst` command](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/subst.mspx?mfr=true) to impersonate their normal network location (assuming, of course, that the current linking is based on mapped drive letters and not UNC's).

Comment: So, you suggest that I rescript the process to run the queries continually until done, possibly copying over the entire DB in the first place?  That's... a good idea. I thought about that at one point, but forgot all about it.

Comment: Here's the next problem (may have to make a new question for this).  How do I convince my non-technical boss that I need to fuss with the reporting process? Again, it's a political issue.

Comment: Put it in non-technical terms.  Tell him, I can spend four hours fixing this problem so that it runs smoothly.  Or I can spend 20 minutes baby-sitting this process for the foreseeable future.  We should see a positive return on investment in X number of weeks/months, etc.  Honestly, the political question may be harder than the technical one :)